# Как запустить веб-страницу через исполняемый скрипт в Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

1. Создал простой скрипт в исполняемом файле:

   ```
    #!/bin/sh

    sudo chmod +x WebPage.html

    sudo sh ./WebPage.html
   ```
2. Дал файлу расширение `sh`
3. Дал файлу разрешение быть исполняемым
4. Запускаю файл в терминале путем ввода команды `sh MyScript.sh`
5. Тишина...

Как при запуске этого скрипта запустить html страницу, которая в нем объявляется?

Чтобы произошло открытие страницы в браузере так, будто я кликнул по html файлу мышкой?

Вроде простейшие две строки.

Может делаю что не правильно?

Comment: а что Вы хотите увидеть? запустит html страницу в консоли - это достаточно странное желание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Веб-страница не является исполняемым файлом, поэтому ее можно запустить только через исполняемый файл ,который бы ее интерпретировал.

Например так: `firefox WebPage.html`

Comment: Отлично, супер, спасибо!

Comment: ну тогда лучше уже использовать xdg-open, который по расширениям правильно подберет, чем запускать.